# Como iterar sobre clases/records con diferentes atributos?

Tags: c#, sql-server

hasta ahora tenia un modelo de datos que ingresaban desde el cliente como el siguiente:

```
public record InsertProductModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string? Units { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string? Images { get; set; }
}
```

que lo ingresaba a la base de datos de la sigueinte forma:

```
 public Producto InsertProduct(InsertProductModel model, MQMContext db)
        {
            var user = db.Usuarios.Where(el => el.IdUsuario == model.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

            Producto newProduct = new Producto(); //para mandar nuevo producto a la db

            if (user == null)
                return newProduct;

            newProduct.IdUsuario = model.UserId;
            newProduct.Nombre = model.Name;
            newProduct.Descripcion = model.Description;
            newProduct.Precio = model.Price;
            newProduct.Unidades = model.Units;

            db.Productos.AddRange(newProduct);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return newProduct;
        }
```

hasta aqui no tube problemas, es bien sencillo, pero ahora el modelo de datos que ingresa es el siguiente:

```
public record InsertProductModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public List<string>? Name { get; set; }
    public List<string>? Description { get; set; }
    public List<string>? Units { get; set; }
    public List<decimal>? Price { get; set; }
    public List<string>? Images { get; set; }

}
```

donde hay solo un int y el resto son listas de diferentes tipos, lo que necesito es iterar sobre las listas e ir metiendo cada posicion del array de cada lista en un registro en la db, o sea Name[0], Description[0], ....etc van en un registro de la db y asi

No consigo entender que tipo de dato debo iterar con foreach siendo que son distintos:

```
foreach(InsertProductModel el in model){
   ....
}
```

por supuesto no funciona, estoy perdido...

**EDITADO:**
Aqui he conseguido hacer algo, pero estoy muy seguro que es una mala forma de hacerlo, ya que aunque el iterador funcione solo se graba el ultimo registro, y si coloco el ds.saveChanges() dentro del iterador obtengo un error...

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.Name.Count; i++)
            {
                newProduct.IdUsuario = model.UserId;
                newProduct.Nombre = model.Name[i];
                newProduct.Descripcion = model.Description[i];
                newProduct.Precio = model.Price[i];
                newProduct.Unidades = model.Units[i];

                db.Productos.AddRange(newProduct);
            }
db.SaveChanges();
```

Aunque pueda solucionar lo de db.saveChanges() me parece que el for es una mala idea.

**ACTUALIZADO**
Este es el modelo de datos que me llegan del cliente:

```
{
 "userId": 10,
 "name": ["Alimento 1","Alimento 2"]
 "description":["Descripcion 1","Descripcion 2"],
 "units": ["kilos","Kilos"],
 "price": [960.60,740],
 "images": ["Imagen 1", "Imagen 2"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo del `for` es una buena idea para guardar en tu caso `ProductModel`

El problema es que tienes una lista por cada atributo de dicho objeto.
Mejor es tener una lista del objeto, así solo recorres la lista de objetos y no cada una de las listas que tienes en cada atributo.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

De esta manera obtienes una lista de InsertProductModel que es tu objeto que tiene todos los valores. Entonces con esto ya no tienes una lista para cada atributo, ahora tienes una lista de tu objeto completo.

```
public class ListInsertProductModel
{
    public List<InsertProductModel> ListaInsertProductModel { get; set; }
}
```

Y ese objeto es el que esperas recibir. Entonces cuando tengas la variable `ListaInsertProductModel` solo la recorres y vas guardando lo que tienes:

```
///Ejemplo como si tuvieras el objeto lleno
ListInsertProductModel model = new ListInsertProductModel(); 


///Se recorre la lista del objeto.
foreach (InsertProductModel el in model.ListaInsertProductModel)
{
    db.Productos.AddRange(el);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Disculpa pero no entiendo a que te refieres con una sola lista. Deberia modificar el insertProductModel? De que manera hacer una sola lista si hay diferentes tipos? Soy muy novato con c#, en js no tenemos estos problemas, jaja

Comment: @HernánGarcia Revisa la actualización de la respuesta.

Comment: Ahi coloque el modelo de datos que llega del cliente, los arreglos los debo iterar, creo no hay otra alternativa, yo debo guardar tantos registros como elementos tenga el arreglo, no logro darme cuenta como usaria tu modelo

Comment: @HernánGarcia para la próxima es mejor que especifiques que los datos los recibes de esa manera. Para no dejar una pregunta tan abierta. 
Pero de la manera que lo aplicas seria una opción.

Comment: Ok, pero como dije mas arriba obtengo el siguiente error cuando tengo el db.SaveChanges() dentro del ciclo for: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Productos' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF, por lo que estoy leyendo esto se debe a que como la columna idProducto de la db es autoincrementable se produce el error al querer meter datos en esa columna, pero yo no estoy tocandola, no se que esta pasando. Si el db.SaveChanges() lo coloco fuera del for, solo me graba el ultimo producto

Comment: @HernánGarcia Intenta usar db.Productos.Add(newProduct), en ves de usar el AddRange()